# How to change text between two words?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

```
<input type="text" id="text">
<input type="button" value="change" id="change">    

<div id="here">
   First to change Second    
    <div class="additional">__RANDOM DATA FROM DATABASE__</div>
</div>

$('#change').click(function(){
   var text = $('#text').val();

   $('#here').html(); 
})
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xHucz/)

How can i change text between two words? In this example if i click change button then text form input should replace text between First and Second.
For example in input is: "my new text" then after click should be in div:

**First my new text Second**

I must use only javascript - jquery, becauce i receive div from other server and i can't modify html.

---

Sorry for all - i edited my question. This has other div.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xHucz/2/

Comment: Another option is to modify the HTML yourself (with javascript), you can create a span with an id that you can use in the future multiple times: http://jsfiddle.net/xHucz/20/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not store prefix and suffix?

```
$('#change').click(function(){
  var prefix = "First ";
  var suffix = " Second";
  var text = $('#text').val();

  $('#here').html(prefix + text + suffix); 
})
```

**Following your edit**. I'm afraid this will be the case for regex then. For example:

```
var oldHtml = $("#here").html();
var newHtml = oldHtml.replace(/First\b(.*)\bSecond/, "First " + text + " Second");
$("#here").html(newHtml);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

http://jsfiddle.net/xHucz/16/

```
$('#change').click(function(){
  var text = $('#text').val();
  var html = $('#here').html(); 

  $('#here').html(html.replace(/(to change)/, text)); 
})
```

Comment: -1: The OP specifically said the HTML could not be changed. You have added a span tag

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
$('#here').html("First "+ $('#text').val()+ "Second ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
var text = $('#text').val();
$("#here").text($('#here').text().replace("to change", text));
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xHucz/18/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. It is general approach. So you should modify it due to need

```
var newText = oldText.replace(/^(\w+).*?(\w+)$/, "$1 my new text $2")
```

P.S. I haven't test this careful but for first sight it works.

Acording to your code you have  just after your Second word
I can suggest next :

```
var newText = oldText.replacereplace(/^(\w+).*?(\w+)(([^<]+)(<div.*))$/m, "$1 my new text $2$3")
```

Comment: That will not actually work with the updated question, there will be a lot of other data before `$`

Comment: Oh I see. Ok. in this case Are the **First** and **Second** are static? Or is any other static information by what you can detect first and/or second word?